# Output for merged array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

Hopefully this isn't a dupe, but I wasn't able to find a specific answer. I have to arrays of hashes:

```
 a1 = [{"aws_ebs_stripe"=>"/dev/xvdi"}, {"aws_ebs_stripe"=>"/dev/xvdj"}, {"aws_ebs_stripe"=>"/dev/xvdk"}, {"aws_ebs_stripe"=>"/dev/xvdl"}]

 a2 = [{"volume_id"=>"vol-001011"}, {"volume_id"=>"vol-010110"}, {"volume_id"=>"vol-101101"}, {"volume_id"=>"vol-011001"}]
```

I'm combining these with some code I found earlier

```
 Hash[a1.zip(a2.map { |i| i.include?(',') ? (i.split /, /) : i })]
```

The idea is to output this as JSON with `pretty_generate`, but something isn't quite right with the first hash in the output:

```
      {
      "{\"aws_ebs_stripe\"=>\"/dev/xvdi\"}": {
        "volume_id": "vol-001011"
      } .... snip
```

Ideally, the JSON should look like this

```
   "aws_ebs_stripe: /dev/xvdi": {
      "volume_id": "vol-001011"
    }
```

I'm unsure of the best way to clean this up.

Comment: Why not just require json and then call to_json on the hashes?

Comment: You want the hash you are constructing to be the value of `:aws`. Correct? In `a2.map { |i|...`, `i` is a hash, so `i.include?(',')` is true if `i` has a key `','`. Is that what you intend?

Comment: that get emitted as part of a larger hash

Comment: I think you're going to have to be a bit clearer about how you'd like the resulting JSON to actually look.

Comment: Why are you calling `.map` on `a2`? The output seems to be precisely identical to a simpler `Hash[a1.zip(a2)]`.

Comment: I tried that and got the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that the `a1` array will always contain only single-key hashes, this is one approach.

```
require 'json'
Hash[a1.map{ |el| "#{el.keys.first}: #{el.values.first}" }.zip(a2)].to_json

# => "{\"aws_ebs_stripe: /dev/xvdi\":{\"volume_id\":\"vol-001011  \"}, ...
```

For a more generic approach to handle multiple key-value pairs in the hashes within `a1`, something like this.

```
Hash[a1.map{ |el| el.map { |k,v| "#{k}: #{v}" } }.flatten.zip(a2)].to_json
```

As mentioned elsewhere though, you might want to improve your data structure if possible.

Comment: Awesome! The generic approach did what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like for some reason your hash aws_ebs_stripe is being interpreted as a string but as Cary S. mentioned the hash output you presented in your question would not be generated by the code you posted. When I run the code you posted and use ap(awesome_print) on the output I get this:

```
{
    { "aws_ebs_stripe" => "/dev/xvdi" } => {
        "volume_id" => "vol-001011"
    },
    { "aws_ebs_stripe" => "/dev/xvdj" } => {
        "volume_id" => "vol-010110"
    },
    { "aws_ebs_stripe" => "/dev/xvdk" } => {
        "volume_id" => "vol-101101"
    },
    { "aws_ebs_stripe" => "/dev/xvdl" } => {
        "volume_id" => "vol-011001"
    }
}
```

But still the JSON will always be escaped based on the way you are creating it. Look at what happens when you call .keys on the hash you are creating:

```
     :051 > ap h.keys
[
    [0] {
        "aws_ebs_stripe" => "/dev/xvdi"
    },
    [1] {
        "aws_ebs_stripe" => "/dev/xvdj"
    },
    [2] {
        "aws_ebs_stripe" => "/dev/xvdk"
    },
    [3] {
        "aws_ebs_stripe" => "/dev/xvdl"
    }
]
```

and h.values:

```
    :052 > ap h.values
[
    [0] {
        "volume_id" => "vol-001011"
    },
    [1] {
        "volume_id" => "vol-010110"
    },
    [2] {
        "volume_id" => "vol-101101"
    },
    [3] {
        "volume_id" => "vol-011001"
    }
]
```

It seems like you need to get the data structure right so it will convert to json in a more usable way.

Comment: I think that's where I'm unclear, the best way to merge these arrays.